# How do I get a keyboard shortcut to translate a google chrome webpage? Not looking for auto-translate options

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-translate

I need to frequently translate the webpage manually for work purpose. Although not looking for auto-translate options, I need a keyboard shortcut or a handy extension to translate the page. The right click option on google or the google chrome translator extension need multiple clicks in order to translate. The middle mouse button to translate the whole web page would do some good to me.

I tried looking out for extensions out of which context menus was related to my issue. I couldn't figure out how it works.

The right click option on chrome has 7th option for translate page which is not handy. I need it to be the first option on right click or the middle mouse button to translate the google page would help.

I am working on windows and not MAC.

Comment: I'm also looking for such chrome extension (for Mac) - please suggest us

Answer (score 1):

I was have same problem and found solution. You can use add on for FireFox named TWO it can be downloaded from https://addons.mozilla.org like general add on, but if u don't use firefox and use chrome for example u need to go on github of developers this extention https://github.com/FilipePS/Traduzir-paginas-web and go up throw instaling guidline  "Chrome, Edge and Brave (With CRX and auto update)".  And then u can use it in chrome and can set up any hotkey for translate. Also don't remember turn off standard pop up google translate for each page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following sequences:

1. select text or skip this step for the whole page translation
2. click right mouse button or Shift+F10 or Context Menu
3. press "t"

It was working on Ubuntu, didn't check it on Windows.

Comment: Well if you have websites disabling Context menu this won't work, you can enable it back using `javascript:void(document.oncontextmenu=null); ` in the Console tab `F12` in most cases. I was hoping to see if can assign shortcuts in Chrome manually.